# Avoiding blank spaces in vertical blocks of a website

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to understand how to change a small thing in a website, but I can't figure out how to do it.
I have a grid of articles organized in two columns, and I would like the various blocks to be separated avoiding the blank space as in figure https://i.stack.imgur.com/tNCFd.png
But I don't know which kind of properties I should set.

Comment: Would you please post your code on jsfiddle?

Comment: This is huge. Not your fault, just one of the recurring questions with no simple answers. Consider using Javascript and take a look at [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/)

Comment: Hi Andrea, Masonry is definitely over my capabilities... Thanks anyway!

Hi xiaoyi, this is the code in the child theme:

/* colonne home page */
#content div.articolo { display:inline-block; clear:none; min-height: 10px; }
#content > div.articolo:nth-child(even) { width:48%; float:left; clear:both; }
#content > div.articolo:nth-child(odd) { width:48%; float:right; }
#content > div.articolo:first-child { width:100%; float:none; clear:both; } 

(colonne=columns, articolo=article)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT - Clarified answer (to clarified question in comments)**

There's a rule in the parent theme:

```
#content .post { margin-bottom: 12px; }
```

You need to override this rule in your child theme and set

```
#content > div.articolo .post { margin-bottom:0; }
```

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

<s>First off, I **strongly** suggest that you don't just throw a heavy jQuery library (i.e. masonry) at a project that can be fixed with simple CSS.</s>

Secondly, from the code in your comments - which is this:

```
#content div.articolo { display:inline-block; clear:none; min-height: 10px; } 
#content > div.articolo:nth-child(even) { width:48%; float:left; clear:both; } 
#content > div.articolo:nth-child(odd) { width:48%; float:right; } 
#content > div.articolo:first-child { width:100%; float:none; clear:both; }
```

You should change it to this:

```
#content div.articolo { display:block; clear:none; min-height: 10px; } 
#content > div.articolo:nth-child(even) { width:50%; float:left; clear:both; } 
#content > div.articolo:nth-child(odd) { width:50%; float:right; } 
#content > div.articolo:first-child { width:100%; float:none; clear:both; }
```

Note the only things that I changed were the `width` (changed to 50%) and I changed `display: inline-block` to `display: block`

`display: inline-block` preserves whitespace (converts many to one) in the markup, so if you have a space in your markup after a closing div that is `display: inline-block`, you'll see a space in your browser. Chances are, that is why the developer set the widths to `48%`, to (poorly) account for the fact that there was a space appearing after each article block (because it was `display: inline-block`) meaning that each block couldn't be set to 50% width, because then they wouldn't appear next to each other (because 50% + 50% + a space > 100%)

Comment: Sorry, Adam, I didn't explain well: I didn't want to avoid spacing between columns but vertical space between articles.

Comment: @ale - you've got code that you aren't showing. Using the code that you've showed us, I've created a fiddle, which, you can see, doesn't have any vertical spaces - http://jsfiddle.net/rmgpshfy/2/ Please post a link to your site (preferred), or all relevant code - i.e. something where we can see the problem being reproduced.

Comment: no, it just reduces the distance between posts, but it doesn't avoid the blank spaces.

Comment: What blank spaces? Can you highlight them in your image that you posted?

Comment: My bad, you mean what happens when you have a long article next to a short article - you must use `masonry`

Comment: Hi @Adam, thank you anyway. Just a last question: I'm trying to understand how to use Masonry, but I couldn't find an easy explanation of it (I'm not really a web developer). Any suggestions on resources to study this library and understand how to use it?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the height of each *article* to 'auto' with suitable margin-bottom. You'll still get some space below where two articles height are less than the corresponding articles in the other column.

Look at the item columns on http://www.ebuyer.com/ - this illustrates the effect.

Comment: Hi Pat, I think the relevant code is this one:

/* colonne home page */
#content div.articolo { display:inline-block; clear:none; min-height: 10px; }
#content > div.articolo:nth-child(even) { width:48%; float:left; clear:both; }
#content > div.articolo:nth-child(odd) { width:48%; float:right; }
#content > div.articolo:first-child { width:100%; float:none; clear:both; }

Should I change min-height: 10px; to height:auto; ?

Answer (score 0):

Pretty difficult to say from just an image. If the margin is in the html elements, you can try to set margin and padding to 0px; if the whitespace is in the bitmaps, crop them.